# WPF: Circular progress bar

Tags: wpf

I have looked around everywhere on this subject, found quite a bit of information, it all looks very complex. I have found [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28098/A-WPF-Pie-Chart-with-Data-Binding-Support) which is really good.

But it doesn't really breakdown how to calculate the values to enter into the ArcSegment to make a full circle, does anyone have any advice. Just show me how to make an ArcSegment which will start at one point and go around 360 and I will work from there.

Comment: I was in the same situation as yours and this blog helped me. I hope for you  too. http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2008/01/Mathematics-of-ArcSegment.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done exactly this, as described in the blog post:

http://dragablz.net/2015/09/15/bending-the-wpf-progressbar/

Answer (score 10):

I have the better solution in form of highly customizable open-source project: https://github.com/panthernet/XamlRadialProgressBar

You can style it as you like or examine the code and create your own beast :)
[image]